# Setting up Webform CiviCRM with an optional contribution/payment

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, stripe

I have a Webform-CiviCRM form that has CiviCRM functionality enabled. It has a contribution field tied to a CiviCRM contribution page using the Stripe payment extension, and which has no minimum value required. I've set it up as a radio button with a choice of a monetary contribution of a set amount, or zero.

Whenever I try to use the form and select the zero dollar option, the credit card fields disappear as expected, but then on form submit I get this message:

> **Payment Error Response:** Error: The card number is not a valid credit card number.

Is this a Stripe extension issue or a Webform-CiviCRM issue?

Answer (score 2):

It was a [Stripe Payment Extension](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe) issue. I thought I was on the latest version but must have been a few commits back. Updating the files to the latest `4.6-dev` version and then visiting the **Manage Extensions** page to run database updates was all I needed.